# Rails3 + Globalize3, how to write clean queries without translation table prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, globalization

i'm trying out the Globalize3 gem for Rails 3.0 now i'm wondering how you can write clean queries. I'm having a Product model with a translatable title and description and a non translatable price. Now i wanted to search for all the Products where the title or description contain a certain keyword. This is what i got:

```
@products = Product.with_translations(I18n.locale).where("product_translations.title like '%#{@keyword}%' or product_translations.description like '%#{@keyword}%'")
```

This works, but as you can see you need to prefix title and product with the translation table ('product_translations').

I would like something like this:

```
@products = Product.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(:title => @keyword).or().where(:description => @keyword)
```

I know this will not be the same as like :) but i want just want to know what is possible and what not without prefixing the columns.

kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 0):

There is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` when you selecting data. Your column `title` become ambiguous without pointing to translations table.
I think that it isn't possible